# Maze solving algorithm -> iteration technique does not catch all special cases

Tags: javascript, node.js, solver, maze

I just build a maze solver algorithm in JS. It works fine, but there are two special cases, where it does not.

1. The program also generates a maze beforehand. If the target (a hat ("^") character) is generated to the starting point of the maze, I want the program to generate a new maze. But this somehow does not work :(
2. The program iterates from upper left to the bottom right and checks it's surrounding positions for a hat or a field character. The problem is, if the maze looks like this, the program stops and does not work:

```js
[ [ '*', 'O', 'O', 'O', '^' ],
  [ '░', 'O', '░', 'O', '░' ],
  [ '░', '░', 'O', 'O', '░' ],
  [ '░', '░', 'O', 'O', '░' ],
  [ '░', '░', '░', '░', '░' ] ]
```

I wanted it to through the whole maze the other way around, but this does not work either...

I'm really happy for any suggestions on these issues! Can anyone give me some feedback on the code? I wrote a lot of comments, the issues should be easy to understand!

Here is the link to my repo: https://github.com/Dimianovic/maze_solver/blob/main/main.js

THANK YOU!

Comment: @Joey no, that would be closed as off-topic, because the code is not working as intended. In addition we don't change what the code does (adding new stuff to it).

Comment: Please read https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of notes about your code...

- The `mazeChecker` function is not performing a **path** search, but rather, is simply looping through the two dimensional array checking for local neighbors of each square.  The `mazeChecker` function needs to find the starting square, and then perform a search beginning at that square, tracking which squares it has visited and which squares it can travel to next, until the goal square is found or there are no more open squares.
- One of the keys to simple code is to leverage data structures.  Specifically, suggest that when building the maze that an edge square is included, and in doing so, there's no need to check array bounds when traversing the squares.  Instead, the code simply needs to check for an edge character, or rather, check for an available square to move to without concern for the bounds of the array.

```js
mazeTest =
[ [ 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X' ],
  [ 'X', '*', 'O', 'O', 'O', '^', 'X' ],
  [ 'X', '░', 'O', '░', 'O', '░', 'X' ],
  [ 'X', '░', '░', 'O', 'O', '░', 'X' ],
  [ 'X', '░', '░', 'O', 'O', '░', 'X' ],
  [ 'X', '░', '░', '░', '░', '░', 'X' ],
  [ 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X' ] ];
 

function printMaze( maze ) {
  let result = '';
  for ( let row = 0; row < maze.length; row++ ) {
    for ( let col = 0; col < maze[ row ].length; col++ ) {
      result += maze[ row ][ col ] + ' ';
    }
    result += '\n';
  }
  return result;
}

console.log( printMaze( mazeTest ) );
```

- Additionally, with the edge character now forming part of the maze, the check for each square around the current square can consist of an array of options that the code can loop through without having to have four (4) sets of `if` statements checking the array bounds.  (This also makes it much easier to adjust the code if wishing to allow diagonal moves, or if changing, say, to a hexagonal stepping stone layout...)  The following excerpt shows the basic concept...

```
    const moveOptions = [ { r: -1, c: 0 }, { r: +1, c: 0 }, { r: 0, c: -1 }, { r: 0, c: +1 } ]; 

        o
        o
        o

    // From the current position, let's look in the immediate vicinity for
    // available squares.
    for ( let mo of moveOptions ) {
      let option = { row: currentSquare.row + mo.r, col: currentSquare.col + mo.c };
      let square = maze[ option.row ][ option.col ];
      
      // Did we find our goal?  If so, set it as the currentSquare and exit
      // the while loop.
      if ( square === '^' ) {
        currentSquare = option;
        break;
      }
      
      // If the square is available, then let's push it on the stack as a
      // starting point for another search.  Also, let's mark the square
      // as being in the stack so we don't visit it again!      
      if ( square === '░' ) {
        nextSquares.push( option );
        maze[ option.row ][ option.col ] = 's';
      }
    }

        o
        o
        o
```

- The code above is an excerpt from a depth first search.  A depth first search simply involves...

  - Create an empty array stack holding the `nextSquares` to move.
  - Define the `currentPosition` and set it to the starting square.
  - While true

    - Loop through the 4 possible squares from the `currentPosition`

      - If the goal square is found, exit the loop and return the result.
      - If an empty square is found, push it on the `nextSquares` stack, marking the square as now being on the stack.  (This is so it is no longer treated as an empty square for the next search of 4 possible squares.)
    - If the `nextSquares` stack is empty, exit indicating the goal square was not found.
    - Otherwise, set `currentPosition` to the square popped off the `nextSquares` stack, looping back to the beginning of the While statement.

Give the above notes some consideration when refactoring your code...

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for taking the time to write all this, I really appreciate it! :) This makes the whole thing a lot clearer to me. I implemented the edge characters and now I will go for the real solving algorithm!

Comment: if you want to, have a look at the finished program :) https://github.com/Dimianovic/maze_solver/blob/main/main.js

Comment: Looks good!  I notice you also made use of array `shift()` rather than `pop()` when moving to the next search square, which performs a breadth first search rather than depth first search!  Glad you were able to make sense of my pseudo code...

Comment: Ok, glad for your feedback again. I should definetely let other people review my code more often :D